# Вопрос по инициализации

Tags: kotlin

Не нашел в документации (или плохо искал :C ) ответ на следующий вопрос:

Инициализировать переменную можно такими способами:

```
val str: String = "abs"
```

Или

```
val str: String
init {
   str = "abs"
}
```

Так вот, равноценны ли данные инициализации?

Comment: переменную где?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman в классе

Comment: в Kotlin у классов есть свойства и поля. вы про что спрашиваете?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman свойство. В котлине инициализация есть: Во время компиляции (conts), в блоке init и поздняя инициализация (lateinit и by lazy). Вопрос в том, равны ли оба выражения в моем вопросе, или есть какие то расхождения в том, когда будет проинициализирована переменная str

Comment: Насколько я понимаю - разницы никакой. Это как в джаве блок инициализации - исключительно для удобства группирования

Answer (score 1):

Если речь о свойстве класса, дефакто оба равноценны, есть еще и третий способ

```
class Foo(val str: String = "abs")
```

Какой эти все способы генерируют байткод я не изучал, возможно там будут различия.